# validateLogin is an undefined function.(javascript exception )

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi i am getting  error as undefined function i think my code is
alright can anyone help in this case?  please help and suggest me a
good tutorial for getting data through webservice via ajax method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

  function validatelogin() {

        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#login").html('');
        var loginId = $('#txt_id').attr('value'); // get username
        var password = $('#txt_pwd').attr('value'); // get password

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/validateLogin",
            data: "lognId=" + loginId + "&password=" + password,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

             success: function (result) {
                    returnVal = result.d;
                    alert(returnVal);
                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    returnVal = '';
                    },
        });
     }


</script>
```

Comment: Well, which function is "undefined"? Also, the trailing comma in the $.ajax options will cause an error in IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can't link a JavaScript source file and define code in the same tag. Just split them up into two separate tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validatelogin() {

        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#login").html('');
        var loginId = $('#txt_id').attr('value'); // get username
        var password = $('#txt_pwd').attr('value'); // get password

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/validateLogin",
            data: "lognId=" + loginId + "&password=" + password,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

             success: function (result) {
                    returnVal = result.d;
                    alert(returnVal);
                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    returnVal = '';
                    },
        });
     }


</script>
```

Citing [MDN on the issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script):

> **src**
>
> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. *script elements with an src attribute specified should not have a script embedded within its tags.*

Answer (score 0):

Your request `content-type` is `JSON` but you're actually passing a `name-value-pairs`. try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({loginId: loginId, password: password}),
```

Also, no need to use `attr('value')` to get input value, you can use `val()` instead.

Comment: Why Stringify the values ?
Just use data: { loginId: loginId, password: password } is enough I guess !
And BTW, the question was why his function is undefined, not something about the Ajax request, even if you're right to say that too !